# How to transfer ETH out of owner's address?

Tags: solidity

I can receive ETH and transfer to owner via:

```
function () payable {
    owner.transfer(msg.value); // owner = address of owner
}
```

How can I have a function which does the reverse thing? Take ETH from owner and transfer to msg.sender?

Answer (score 5):

You can't *take* Eth from anyone.
The contract has only access to Ether which is stored inside the contract. So the owner has to send Ether to the contract which the contract can then send to wherever (for example `msg.sender` in another function call).

Answer (score 0):

using smart contract to transfer from `user address` to `smart contract address` and transfer ETH to the address which you want with:

```
function withdraw(address _to) public {
    _to.transfer(address(this).balance);
}
```