# How can I directly send eth from account to account?

Tags: solidity

Can I directly send eth from account ro account?

Or have I receive() eth in pool and send in accounts from it. But I can't use receive(), because i need to get uint variale together with _value. Receive() does not get parametrs.

I tryed to organize sendig directly by using .balance, but it is not succesful.

```
      ...
      players[i].balance -= valuePlayer[players[i]];
      for (uint q = 0; q < numWinners; q++){
        tempaddr = addrPosition[_rightPosition][q];
        tempaddr.balance += valuePlayer[players[i]] * valuePlayer[tempaddr] / sum_value;
      }
      ...
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to transfer ETH out of owner's address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/54587/how-to-transfer-eth-out-of-owners-address)

Comment: Hi EgorFedorov! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! It isn't clear what are you trying to achieve. Do you want to send ether from one account to another from javascript or you are moving balances inside your contract? Can you show the contract code?